# Feedme import formatting into Refactor from JSON

Tags: redactor, plugin-feedme, json

Having had a bit of a nightmare trying to get content out of Wordpress into Craft via Feedme have written an intermediary script to sanitise the WP XML export into something more palatable (JSON).

However still having issues and it looks like Feedme is breaking the supplied string for HTML content into an array (breaking on commas).

For example:

```
"content":"<p><h2>Importance of passing your MOT first time<\/h2><p>At Rygor, we understand that … </p>"
```

Is being passed into Redactor (via the Feedme debug) as:

```
(
    [type] => text
    [enabled] => 1
    [collapsed] => 
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [body] => ["<p><h2>Importance of passing your MOT first time&lt;\/h2&gt;</h2><p>At Rygor","we understand that it is important to … 
        )
)
```

Oddly the body string has no closing quote.
Any thoughts how best to encode my HTML string or to avoid FeedMe breaking my string into an array?

Comment: Sample JSON > [link](https://gist.github.com/cole007/1ced88f31029083054d238c734cafd24)

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @Dajo on the Craft Discord channel for any other folk out there experiencing similar turns out there was a config set-up for the site wasn't aware of that had set the `dataDelimiter` parameter to  `,` which was exploding the HTML content into an array.

Changing this has sorted the problem!